# Debian install unsuccessfull: DVD, dd, cat, Unetbootin, YUMI, Rufus, Live CD installs do not work

Tags: debian, usb, system-installation

I have an old laptop which runs Windows 7 and Linux Mint perfectly. However, I do not seem to be able to install Debian into it. I tried lots of ways to install with USB stick but failed. Image was debian-update-8.5.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso.

- DVD did not boot
- Live CD failed because it asked for a CD even when the install started from usb
- `sudo dd if=/dev/sde1 of=debian.iso` -> will not boot
- `sudo cat debian.iso > /dev/sde1` -> access denied
- Netinstall stopped because of lack of network card drivers
- YUMI was not able to write to USB
- Unetbootin was able only to download a preselected image, not one with network drivers
- Rufus ... I don't remember what went wrong with it.

How do I install Debian into the laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Debian-Update.iso isn't bootable you need to download a bootable image from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/).

[What are the update CDs/DVDs?](https://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#update-cd)

> Note that update CDs/DVDs are not meant to boot, they just contain the packages needed to upgrade an existing installation. If you don't have that existing installation, then you'll need to use the normal installation CDs/DVDs. After the new system is booted, the updated CD/DVD can be added with `apt-cdrom add`.

Comment: debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso inside YUMI says "Loading /install.amd/vmlinuz... failed: No such file or directory" when selecting any install option.

Comment: With that same image and Unetbootin Debian is now installing.

Comment: Verify the md5 ,must be `443272aea9729ce281a1bc5b258a4243` then create the bootable usb using `dd` : `dd if=debian-8.5.0-amd64-CD-1.iso of=/dev/sde`